# styleUrls path depending on a global variable or service

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to insert a variable path on the styleUrls/templateUrl fields, because for deploying purposes this path can't be derived neither using a fixed absolute path, nor with a fixed relative path.

```
var cssPath = "/foo/bar/css/";
var tmplPath = "/foo/bar/tmpl/";

@Component({
    selector: 'mycomp',
    styleUrls: [  cssPath + 'mycomp.css' ],
    templateUrl: tmplPath + 'mycomp.html'
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

I started a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1vK0hij1DRzEVdmLROz) to play with.